# Android studio app keeps on crashing and showing screen cast error

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be  cast to
>   android.widget.EditTextat
>   com.example.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

This is my kotlin code where error is coming:

```
val Name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etName)

val Password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etpassword)

val Login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnlogin)

val Info = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvinfo)

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/etName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Can your paste your layout xml too?

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have

```
android:id="@+id/etName"
```

in your root `ConstraintLayout`. In code you have

```
val Name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etName)
```

which finds a view by id `etName` and attempts to cast it to `EditText`. The algorithm in `findViewById()` is just a simple tree search that stops at first match which is the root layout for you. If you have another view (such as your `EditText`) with the same id, the search never reaches that deep. Bang, `ClassCastException`.

To fix it, remove the id from the root layout, or change it to something unique within the layout file, and ensure you actually have an `EditText` with id `etName` in the layout.